# global variable in javascript does not change

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I know that I can change the variable by reference it but for some reason I have this code:

```
function getCertInfo() {

    inputHolder = document.getElementById("stdIDNumber").value;
    var holdStudentName;
    var isExist = false;
    contract.methods.isEntity(inputHolder).call().then(function(result) {
        isExist = result;
        console.log(isExist);

    });
    console.log(isExist);

}
```

I have a simple page with an input to insert the student id and button to send it .. 
so the function suppose to go to my smart contract function to check if the id exist in the blockchain or not and return the Boolean

but! 
if I run the code and I put an existing ID .. the first console log will be True which is good but the second one will be False which does it make sense to me!

Comment: If you're calling `.then`, the method is probably asynchronous. By the time the second console log runs, `contract.methods.isEntity(inputHolder).call()` hasn't finished yet, so the value of `isExist` is still `false`.

Comment: so how can I overcome this ..so when it look to the smart contract and find that the ID is exist it will change the variable isExist to false?

Comment: in your case the `isExist` variable only exists within the scope of the `getCertInfo` function since it is declared and initialized within. What's your goal , what problem do you currently have ? Should `getCertInfo` return anything ?

Comment: so my goal is to create a blockchain that store students certificate .. and in the front end ... there are an input filed to put the ID of the student and a button to send that ID  .. then display the student information.. so if a user put an ID and hit send ... I want it to check the blockchain and see if the ID exist or not and if it didnt exist . it will say that the certificate is not found.

Comment: I updated my answer below - please take look and let me know if it helps !

Comment: It works .. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks @asim ! Glad I could help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing issue, since `contract.methods.isEntity().call()` returns a promise (`then`) and is executed asynchronous. Try this:

```js
function getCertInfo() {

   // GET ID FROM USER INPUT
   var inputHolder = document.getElementById("stdIDNumber").value;

   // CHECK IF ID EXISTS
   var isExist = contract.methods.isEntity(inputHolder).call()
   .then(function (result) {

      // DISPLAY RESULT TO USER
      var display = document.getElementById("resultDisplay");
      display.innerHTML = result ? "The Cert exists!" : "Cert doesn't exist!";

      // Then show the result to the user if it exists. 
      // But it has to be within "then" of the resolved Promise
      // Otherwise it would be undefined

   }).catch(function (err) {

     console.log(err.message);

   });

}
```

Then just call the method with a button. The trick is to wait until the Promise is "resolved" and then update a container with the result.

Comment: @asim currently your getCertInfo function seems pretty useless. What's your plan with it ? What's the goal ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work in Javascript. When `.call()` is invoked, the code continues to runs through to log the variable out as `false` first. However, when `.call()` is finished asynchronously, the callback (`then`) runs and changes `isExist` to true and logs that out.

Ideally, when using them, you should be chaining promises when you want to do things sequentially in your app.

```
var isExist = false;
contract.methods.isEntity(inputHolder).call().then(function(result) {
    isExist = result;
    console.log(isExist); //will be whatever result is (let's say true)
}).then(function(){
    isExist = false;
    console.log(isExist); //will be false
});
```